How to stretch cards to fill entire div with HTML/CSS?
I've created two cards on a site I am building. I would like them to span the entire div but I cannot get them to span the width without their size being giant. Ideally, I would like to make the cards shorter height and longer width to span the div. The first image below is what I have now, the second image is what I would like it to become.
The current code that I have for this area follows. Any insight is helpful, thanks!


.alignment {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    column-gap: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 6%;

}

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
  }


.card {
    /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
    box-shadow: 0 5px 13px 0 #000;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #121212;
    border-color: #121212;
    flex-grow: -1;
    width: 30%;
  }
  
  /* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
  .card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 000;
  }

  .card img {
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  }

  .card h3 {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }

  .card h4 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
  }

  #content > div.news > div.alignment.show > div:nth-child(1) > div > h4 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
  }

  #content > div.news > div.alignment.show > div:nth-child(1) > div > p {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  #content > div.news > div.alignment.show > div:nth-child(2) > div > h4 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
  }

  #content > div.news > div.alignment.show > div:nth-child(2) > div > p {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  .card p {
    margin-top: -8px;
  }

  .card .link-a {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }
<div class="alignment">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="image.png" alt="Avatar">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- <h3 style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><span class="small">Lorem Ipsum</span></h3> -->
            <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p class="link-a" style="font-size: 15px;"><a href="next-best-actions">CTA Link</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="image.png" alt="Avatar" style="">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- <h3 style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><span class="small">Lorem Ipsum</span></h3> -->
            <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p class="link-a" style="font-size: 15px;"><a href="next-best-actions">CTA Link</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



Current Display:



Future Display:


What is flex-grow: -1;? Do you mean flex-grow: 1;

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

What you're looking for is probably flex: 1 in your .card, and .card img { width: 100%; object-fit: cover }

The problem with flex-grow: 1 is that it makes the height of the card super tall. I want to create a card that is a long rectangle, not a square.

Can you try this?
I don't know why you used column-gap as % but I think it would be natural not to change depending on the width of the device.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.top .card {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}

.top .card img {
  width: 50%;
}

.top .card .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 16px;
}

.top .card .container h4 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.top .card .container p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.top .card .container .link-a {
  margin-top: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.top .card .container .link-a a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.alignment {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  column-gap: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.alignment .container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

.alignment .card {
  /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
  box-shadow: 0 5px 13px 0 #000;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #121212;
  border-color: #121212;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 30%;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */

.alignment .card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 000;
}

.alignment .card img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.alignment .card .container h4 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.alignment .card .container p {
  margin-top: -8px;
  color: white;
}

.alignment .card .container .link-a {
  margin-top: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.alignment .card .container .link-a a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
}


/* max-width 1200px */

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .top .card {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
  }
  .top .card img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .top .card .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .alignment {
    flex-direction: column;
    column-gap: 0;
    row-gap: 20px;
  }
  .alignment .card {
    /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }
  .alignment .card img {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 220px;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300" alt="Avatar">
      <div class="container">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor
          sit amet.Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p class="link-a" style="font-size: 15px;"><a href="">View Case Study</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alignment">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300" alt="Avatar">
      <div class="container">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p class="link-a" style="font-size: 15px;"><a href="">View Case Study</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300" alt="Avatar">
      <div class="container">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p class="link-a" style="font-size: 15px;"><a href="">View Case Study</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300" alt="Avatar">
      <div class="container">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p class="link-a" style="font-size: 15px;"><a href="">View Case Study</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




This works but doesn't quite do what I want it to. I want to make this card a rectangle that is smaller than the element above seen in the second image. I'm shooting for something shorter in height and that is longer in width rather than the same size / larger.

An alternative approach I've considered is putting the image to the left side of the card and the text to the right side of the card but I haven't explored it quite yet

Then add more codes. Think more about planning. Then I can help you more. @braxton

I've just made a new version of the card and uploaded the code. I've just posted a different question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78921098/how-can-i-make-a-card-like-this-which-is-responsive-in-html-css

So, has the current question been solved...? It's the first time I've experienced a user who registers a single question by dividing it into several. @braxton

No, it is a new question completely

So what is the answer you want from this question? @braxton

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I edited my answer. This would have been a sufficient answer to your question. @braxton

Isn't this what you need?
Additional styles:
.alignment {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 30px;
}

.card {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: auto;
}


This isn't quite what I am looking for, I want the cards to span the full width of the container but be shorter, not their max height
